# How to count amount and percentage from overall amount in one request?

Tags: mysql, sql

I got two tables:

**Shippers** with ***ShipperID***, ***ShipperName*** columns and

**Orders** with ***OrderID***, ***ShipperID*** columns.

I need to select shippers that shipped **an above average** (to column "Sender"), amount of orders they shipped (to column "Items Sent") and **percentage of shipping from overall amount** (to column "Quota", values have to be with '%' sign).

I got two options:

```
 select Shippers.ShipperName, Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderID
 from (
       select 
              Shippers.ShipperName as "Sender",
              count(Orders.OrderID) as "Items Sent",
              (count(Orders.OrderID)*100)/sum(Orders.OrderID) as "Quota"
       from Shippers
       left join Orders
       on Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID
       group by Shippers.ShipperName
      ) Shippers 
       group by Shippers.ShipperName
  having Orders.OrderID > avg(Orders.OrderID);
```

As a result **Syntax error at line 5**

And the second option:

```
select Shippers.ShipperName as "Sender",
       count(Orders.OrderID) as "Items Sent",
       100*count(Orders.OrderID)/(select count(Orders.OrderID) 
                          from Shippers left join Orders
                          on Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID) as "Quota"
from Shippers
left join Orders
on Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID
group by Shippers.ShipperName
having count(Orders.OrderID)>(select count(Orders.OrderID)
            from Shippers left join Orders  
               on Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID) /                 
               (select count(distinct ShipperID) from Shippers);
```

As a result 1064 **syntax error at line 13**;

Data "Shippers":                                       Data "Orders":

```
ShippersID|ShipperName                        OrderID|ShipperID             
----------|----------------                 ---------|----------
       1  |Speedy Express                     10248  |    3
       2  |United Package                     10249  |    1
       3  |Federal Shipping                   10250  |    2
----------|----------------                   10251  |    1
                                              10252  |    2
                                              10253  |    2
                                              10254  |    2
                                              10255  |    3
                                              10256  |    2
                                            ---------|----------
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data so that we may test a possible solution.

Comment: Again, show us sample _data_ so that we may test our queries.  I mean COLUMNS and VALUES.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is a little part. There are more orders

Comment: Here is a [demo using your sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecc75/2).  It appears to be working.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my apologies. I need your help one more time. How should I add "%" to the valued in table in 'num_orders_percent'?

Comment: Use `CONCAT(expression for num_orders_percent, '%')` ... actually strictly speaking you should first _cast_ the value to a character, but MySQL has implicit type conversion and you shouldn't need to

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you. I wish I could help you in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would phrase your query as follows:

```
SELECT s.ShipperName,
       COUNT(*) AS num_orders,
       100 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Shippers t1 LEFT JOIN Orders t2
                         ON t2.ShipperID = t1.ShipperID) AS num_orders_percent
FROM Shippers s
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID
GROUP BY s.ShipperName
HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Shippers t1 LEFT JOIN Orders t2 -- total # orders
                   ON t2.ShipperID = t1.ShipperID) /                    -- divided by
                  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ShipperID) FROM Shippers)      -- total # shippers
```

Everything in my query should seem familiar to you, except for two subqueries, which I will explain here:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Shippers t1 LEFT Orders t2 ON t2.ShipperID = t1.ShipperID
```

This calculates the total number of orders, from all shippers.  It is used to compute the percentage of orders which a given shipper holds as:

```
% orders = # orders / total # orders
```

The `HAVING` clause restricts the result set to only shippers who exceeded the average number of orders.  Here, another subquery is needed:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ShipperID) FROM Shippers
```

This computes the total number of distinct shippers.  The following equation can be used to find the average number of orders per shipper:

```
average # orders = total # orders / total # shippers
```

Here is a demo using the sample data you provided:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: @Amayak I had a slight typo in the `SELECT`, which should have read `SELECT s.ShipperName ...` , please try again

Comment: `select Shippers.ShipperName as "Sender",
 count (Orders.OrderID) as "Item Sent",
 100 * count(Orders.OrderID) / (select count (Orders.OrderID)
 from Shippers.ShipperName left Orders.Order ID
 on Shippers.ShipperID=Orders.OrderID as "Quota"
 from Shippers
 left join Orders
 on Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID
 group by Shippers.ShipperName
 having count (Orders.OrderID) > (select count(Orders.OrderID)
 from Shippers.ShipperName left Orders.OrderID
 on Shippers.ShipperID = Orders.OrderID) / 
 (select count(distinct ShipperID) from Shippers);`
Error at line 3

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis to close the denominator subquery.  Why aren't you using my query?

Comment: I'm using yours. * in count means Orders.OrderID and t1 - shippers and t2 -Orders. Right?

Comment: Sorry, I won't go back and forth.  Update your question to show minimal sample data that everyone can test against.  This will make this so much easier.

Comment: no it's not the right answer. The right answer is:


Sender                 | Items Sent | Quota///////

Federal Shipping  |             68  |    34.69%///////

United Package    |            74   |     37.76%

Comment: @Amayak No, you're wrong.  Only United Package sent an above average amount because it made 5 orders and the average was 4.5.  The other 2 senders were below average and therefore were not reported per your requirements.  I will not spend any more time here, good luck!

Comment: My mistake. It's because I didn't give you the whole data. I'm really sorry. And a huge thanks from me. Your help and your time were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Should be using having for filter the avg

```
 select t1.name, t1.count_order, t1.perc_order
 from (
  select 
      Shippers.ShipperName as name
    , count(Orders.OrderID) as  count_order
    , (count(Orders.OrderID)*100)/sum(Orders.OrderID) as  perc_order
  from Shippers
  left join Orders
  on Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID
  Group by Shippers.ShipperName
  ) t1 
  group by t1.name 
  HAVING count_order > avg( count_order)
```

Comment: It gives me an SQL syntax error in:
'Orders.OrderID)*100/sum(Orders.OrderID)'

Comment: I'm sorry I took your time. I can't understand. It's not working. I think I need to read more.

Comment: Update your question and give us sample data that we can all refer to.  You asked for a fairly complex query, and you can't expect anyone to get it right without even testing it.

Comment: @Amayak   the qiuery you post in your question is dfferent respect what i have posted .. so if you can tell me exactly the error you have with my .. code .. the exact error message please

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but I'm using your's. I just replaced count(*) with count(name of the table) and t1,t2 with the names of the tables. Is it wrong?

Comment: @Amayak   . if you are using TimBiegeleisen  answer  then use is answer for comment  and not  mine so  .. I'm not involved  in issue not related to my answer  please